# If file older than X days -> run command -- CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, forfiles

I'm writing a script for DriveSnapshot run on various Windows Server versions.
I want to run a specific batchfile (fullbackup) if there is a file older than 6 days in a folder.
If there are no such files -> run a differential backup.

I tried:

```
ForFiles /p "path\to\folder" /d -6 /c "cmd /c set var=1"
if %var% == 1 (
   fullbackup.bat
) else (
   diffbackup.bat
)
```

But it seems you can't just run any command within `ForFiles`.

It seems the variable never gets assigned the proper value.

The Microsoft Docs page for `ForFiles` reads:

> Runs the specified command on each file. Command strings should be enclosed in quotation marks.*

I know my command would `set var=1` for every file it finds, but should still work, right?

If there is any better way to go at this problem, please enlighten me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line behind the `/C` switch of the [`forfiles` command](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) are not running in the hosting [`cmd` instance](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html), you are actually even explicitly creating a new one (by `cmd /C`).

But there is a simpler approach, utilising the exit code of `forfiles` together with [conditional execution operators `&&` and `||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
forfiles /P "D:\path\to\folder" /D -6 > nul 2>&1 && (
    "D:\path\to\fullbackup.bat"
) || (
    "D:\path\to\diffbackup.bat"
)
```

Usually I recommend to use [`call`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) to run another batch file from a batch file, but here in this case I intentionally skipped it, because `call "fullbackup.bat"` may return an exit code of the batch file in its own that might unintentionally be recognised by `||`.

If you do need to use `call` when there are other commands following I would use this:

```cmd
forfiles /P "D:\path\to\folder" /D -6 > nul 2>&1 && (
    call "D:\path\to\fullbackup.bat" & goto :NEXT
) || (
    call "D:\path\to\diffbackup.bat"
)
:NEXT
```

Note that `forfiles` also iterates over directories but not just files.

Comment: Thanks! That works as I wanted it to.

To last line: There is either one file or nothing in the folder ATM so it works for now. If it comes to it I would just run multiple checks per subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Use `errorlevel` instead as your current script sets the variable outside of your scripts environment and it never gets passed back to the parent script.

```
ForFiles /p "z:\work" /d -100 /c "cmd /c">nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 call diffbackup.bat else call fullbackup.bat
```

Comment: Thanks! This on also works.
And also thanks for formatting my question ;)